# How to check if Concat value is in a Table List, and how to reject/show user when what they inputted is not in the list

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula, concatenation, countif

I'm making an excel file where the user has to input inventory movements.

I initially used only one column that had data validation but it took a long time to encode the Item because all Items kept reoccuring in different sizes (Ex. Choco Cake 6", Choco Cake 8", Choco Cake Slice, Mango Cake 6", Brownies PC, Brownies HLF, Brownies WHL, etc.)

For ease of use, I thought of separating the Type (Choco Cake, Mango Cake), from the Sizes (6", 8", SLC) so that encoding would be a lot faster.

My problem was what if the user paired the wrong Item Type with the wrong Size, and I wanted to prevent that, or at least alert the encoder if they did that.

The solution I came up with was to use a countif function (see below) but there's hundreds of items to encode everyday for just one branch and I'm afraid the excel file will get bogged down really quickly.

ex.

I also created a named lists in a table (Item) as a masterlist that contains the full Item names (Ex. Choco Cake 6", Choco Cake 8", Choco Cake Slice, Mango Cake 6", Brownies PC, Brownies HLF, Brownies WHL, etc.)

| Type | Size | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Choco Cake | 6" | Choco Cake 6" |
| Mango Cake | WHL | WRONG SIZE |

This is the current formula for the Item column

=IF(COUNTIF(Item,CONCAT(A2," ",B2))=1,CONCAT(A2," ",B2),"WRONG SIZE")

Is there a better, less resource heavy way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: two ideas: dependant validation lists (you will find a lot of answers here on SO) or data validation highlightning wrong combinations.

Comment: Which version of excel do you have?  There's a lot of really good stuff in O365 that makes this easy.

Comment: How do you use data validation to highlight wrong combinations? Using conditional formatting? Wouldn’t that be resource heavy as well?

Comment: We use office 365. What could we use to make this easier/less resource heavy? Thank you.